# Error in spherical coordinate calculation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, volume, spherical-coordinates

When I try to calculate the volume of a sphere of radius a, I set up the following 
$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{a}\rho^2\sin{\phi}\  d\rho\ d\phi\ d\theta$, and from this I get $\frac{2}{3}\pi a^3$, which is a half of the supposed $\frac{4}{3}\pi a^3$. Which is wrong in my calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$-\cos \pi+ \cos 0 = 2$$ Not the $1$ you probably used by ignoring the $0$ at the lower limit.